# Cognos report studio filter from Feb data to last closed month

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

**Cognos** report studio filter from Feb data to last closed month.

I need to build a report that should show data from Feb to last closed month.

If I run the report in March, it should show the data only for Feb.
If I run the report in Dec, it should show the data from Feb to Nov.
If I run the report in Jan, it should show the data from Last Year Feb to last year Dec.
If I run the report in Feb, it should show the data from Last Year Feb to current year Jan.

Is anyone can help?

#Cognos # CognosBI #CognosDeveloper.

Comment: Your logic is inconsistent.  If you run the report in March through December, you want data through **this** month.  If you run the report in January or February, you want the data through **last** month.  Is that correct?

Comment: And you say "to last closed month".  If you run the report in March, how is March already closed?

Comment: Thanks Doug. Thats my typo. If  I run the report, it should show Feb to Last Closed Month Data. When I run the report in Dec, it should show Feb to Nov. When I run the report in March it should show data only for Feb.. Hope it clarifies you and helps for me.

Comment: I edited the post. Please suggest a best suitable answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter expression of [Itemtobefiltered] between [StartDate] and [EndDate]

The [StartDate] query calculation should have an expression of:

```
if (extract(month,current_date)<=2)
then 
(_first_of_month(_add_years(current_date,-1)))
else
(cast(cast(extract(year,current_date),varchar(4))+'-02-01',date))
```

The [EndDate] query calculation should have an expression of:

```
_last_of_month(current_date)
```

Comment: The above will get you started, given all the discrepancies dougp pointed out